# Oracle 1:n efficient query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've a two tables A and B, where a record in A is mapped to several records in B. There is query which shows the records of table A, along with all the mapped records in table B in a single line, like :

```
TABLE A
--------
ID  Name  Tag ......
1    X    213
2    Y    222

TABLE B
--------
ID    ACCESS_AREA
1     101
1     104
1     105
2     101
2     103
```

The query is like:

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       Tag ,.....,
       (SELECT WM_CONCAT(ACCESS_AREA)
          FROM B
          WHERE ID = A.ID ) Access_areas
  FROM A
```

Though the above works, the performance of the query is very low, as the number of records in both the tables are very large. Any filtering or sorting on the `access_areas` results in further low performance.

We thought of using a materialized view to compute the values before hand, so that it'll be a simple join, but mv does not allow fast refresh on commit for such queries using aggregate functions.

Another option was to add a column to table A, which contained the computed values from B and use a trigger on table B to update the new column if any changes were done. But this also is not feasible as you cannot query the same table where the trigger is.

As a last resort we've decided to implement the second option and update the column through the application code, which is very tedious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You've not shown the EXPLAIN plan for the query nor what indexes exist for the tables. But far more importantly you've not told us what you are doing with this data - why do you need to access large amounts of data at a time? Why do you need to denosmalise the results?

You could create a view incorporating both the materialized view and the raw data updated since the snapshot was taken (and potentially removing updated entries which are no longer valid) but without some of idea of how the data is used / whether it is ever updated rather than just added to it's not really possible to advise on specifics.

Comment: I'm sorry, whatever I mentioned was an example which resembled the scenario I'm facing. We actually have two more similar computed columns. Also, unfortunately I've no say in the design spec.

Comment: There is a front end interface which lists all the records from the first table and its associated tables in a single page, thus the query

Comment: By 'Page' do you mean HTML? Then don't worry about it - the performance problems with the query are **nothing** compared to the performance problems created by delivering this via HTTP and trying to render it using HTML. Time to start polishing up your CV

Answer (score 0):

**1. Replace `WM_CONCAT` with either `LISTAGG` or `COLLECT`.**

Large string aggregation can be quite expensive because of the frequent context switches between SQL and PL/SQL.  `WM_CONCAT`, and `STRAGG`, are very popular, but they are both very inefficient.  If you're on 11gR2, always use `LISTAGG`.  If you're not on 11gR2 yet, then use the `COLLECT` method.  [This page](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515) explains the different methods and has some performance comparisons.

**2. Materialized view.**

I know you said you already tried that, and I don't have a lot of experience with materialized views, but I think that they should work in this case.  A rowid materialized view won't work, but a [primary key materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54164) should.

(Unless there are some other specific reasons preventing it, in which case we may need all the details to troublesheet the problem: full query and DDL for tables, materialized view, and materialized view log.)

**3. Explain plan.**

As symcbean mentioned, it may be a plan issue.  If you're only using a small number of the rows, are indexes being used?  But in addition to the explain plan we need to know your expectations for this query.  If the query takes a second, but returns 200KB of data, then your network or browser may be the real bottleneck.

---

I'm not sure if #2 or #3 will help, but you should always implement #1.  I consider `WM_CONCAT` and `STRAGG` to be bugs - there's just no good reason to use them when there are much better alternatives.